# Firebase don't send me my value into my variable

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've got a code which normally should return to me a value from Firebase.

My Firebase struct is :

```
Experience{
    UserId{
        LDG_DAY: "4"
        LDG_NIGHT: "0"
        APCH_IFR: "0"
    }
}
```

My code is :

```
func getUserExp(){
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let Date = self.flightDate.text
 ref.child("Experience")/*.child(userID!)*/.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) {(snapshot) in
            if snapshot.hasChild(userID!){
                let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary


                let ldg_day = value?["LDG_DAY"] as? String ?? "123"
                let ldg_night = value?["LDG_NIGHT"] as? String ?? "0"
                let apch_ifr = value?["APCH_IFR"] as? String ?? "0"


                self.intLdgDay = Int(ldg_day)!
                self.intLdgNight = Int(ldg_night)!
                self.intApchIfr = Int(apch_ifr)!

                print("string = \(ldg_day) int = \(self.intLdgDay)")



            }
        }
}
```

Now the code didn't work as I would like... In fact my code return the basic `as? String ?? "123"` value but the snapshot.value get the good value from firebase ... 
What's wrong ? I use this code for many other part of my app and no problems about it ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: You're observing a node Experience/uid_x and want to work with the child nodes of LDG_DAY, LDG_NIGHT and APCH_IFR. But you're looking to see if the userID node *exists within that node* as one of the child nodes, which it doesn't so it will always fail. [.hasChild](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDataSnapshot#/c:objc(cs)FIRDataSnapshot(im)hasChild:) looks for the child within the node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to ensure the node exists before trying to read the child data.

**NOTE:**

I see the path to read has the uid commented out so it's unclear if you intended to read a single user (leaving in the uid) or if you actually wanted to load every user at one time (thousands). This answer assumes you are intending to read that specific user node only. See @Callam answer if you intended to read ALL of the users nodes at one time.

The code you have now is using snapshot.hasChild which looks within the node to see if the child, the users uid exists, and it doesn't so the code will always fail.

```
if snapshot.hasChild(userID!)
```

I think what you want to do is use snapshot.exists to ensure it's a valid node before reading. Here's the code:

```
let experienceRef = self.ref.child("Experience")
let usersExpRef = experienceRef.child(uid)
usersExpRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
    if snapshot.exists() {
        let value = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]
        let ldg_day = value["LDG_DAY"] as? String ?? "123"
        print("string = \(ldg_day)")
    } else {
        print("the \(uid) node does not exist")
    }
}
```

I would also suggest safely unwrapping options before attempting to work with them as they could be nil, and that would crash your code.

```
guard let thisUser = Auth.auth().currentUser else { return }
let uid = thisUser.uid
```

Note I also replaced the old objc NSDictionary with it's Swifty counterpart [String: Any]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your struct is from the root, and `Experience` contains more than one user ID, your code is currently observing the value for all user IDs since the `/*.child(userID!)*/` is commented out.

Therefore you are requesting every user's experience and checking on the client if the current user exists as a child – this will succeed if the current user's ID is present at `Experience/$uid`.

```
ref.child("Experience")/*.child(userID!)*/.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
    if snapshot.hasChild(userID!) {
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
```

Now we have a snapshot with all Experiences and we've confirmed that it has a child for the current user's ID – we would need to get *that* child and cast the value of that to a dictionary.

```
let value = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: userID).value as? NSDictionary
```

This fixes the issue but obviously, we don't want to download every experience on a single user's device, and they maybe shouldn't even have the permission to request that reference location either.

---

So if you uncomment `.child(userID!)`, the snapshot will be of just one Experience, so `snapshot.hasChild(userID!)` will fail. Instead, you can use `snapshot.exists()` and/or a conditional cast to determine if the snapshot for the `userID` is existent and/or thereby castable.

```
func getUserExp() {
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let Date = self.flightDate.text

    ref.child("Experience").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            let value = snapshot.value as? [String:String]

            let ldg_day = value?["LDG_DAY"] ?? "123"
            let ldg_night = value?["LDG_NIGHT"] ?? "0"
            let apch_ifr = value?["APCH_IFR"] ?? "0"

            self?.intLdgDay = Int(ldg_day)!
            self?.intLdgNight = Int(ldg_night)!
            self?.intApchIfr = Int(apch_ifr)!

            print("string = \(ldg_day) int = \(self.intLdgDay)")
        } else {
            print("experience for \(snapshot.key) doesn't exist")
        }
    }
}
```

---

You can clean this up a bit with a struct and extension.

*`// Experience.swift`*

```
struct Experience {
    var ldg_day: String
    var ldg_night: String
    var apch_ifr: String
}

extension Experience {
    static var currentUserRef: DatabaseReference? {
        return Auth.auth().currentUser.flatMap {
            return Database.database().reference(withPath: "Experience/\($0.uid)")
        }
    }

    init?(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        guard snapshot.exists() else { return nil }

        let value = snapshot.value as? [String:String]

        self.ldg_day = value?["LDG_DAY"] ?? "123"
        self.ldg_night = value?["LDG_NIGHT"] ?? "0"
        self.apch_ifr = value?["APCH_IFR"] ?? "0"
    }
}
```

Et voilà,

```
func getUserExp() {
    Experience.currentUserRef?.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { [weak self] in
        if let experience = Experience(snapshot: $0) {
            self?.intLdgDay = Int(experience.ldg_day)!
            self?.intLdgNight = Int(experience.ldg_night)!
            self?.intApchIfr = Int(experience.apch_ifr)!

            print("string = \(experience.ldg_day) int = \(self.intLdgDay)")
        } else {
            print("experience for \($0.key) doesn't exist")
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: I don't think this addresses the question which is why is the code not reading the node in question. It's not wrong but may send the OP off in unneeded directions; it's lot of extra code (structs, extensions etc) just to read three nodes from Firebase. It's fine to cast snapshot.value to a dict; that's common practice as it's a dict of key: value pairs. Assigning it to another snapshot and then to a dict is unnecessary in this case. Looking closely as their code, it's not downloading every user experience, it's downloading one user Experience, which is shown by the path Experience/userID.

Comment: @Jay but OP has commented out the child containing the user ID, so the resulting ref is just Experience – `snapshot.hasChild(userID!)` would succeed, but `snapshot.value as? NSDictionary` would be a dictionary of all Experiences rather than of one.

Comment: @flyer74 Well look that! You are absolutely correct, that is commented out. Obviously leaving the uid in simplifies the entire thing as it's pulling just one user (per my answer). If it is *supposed* to be commented out then the code in the OP's question won't work at all since (as you pointed out) it's getting every single user (potentially thousands of them) at one time and not iterating over them. Of course the use case appears to be for a single user. Perhaps the OP can clarify?

Comment: Great catch btw. I updated my answer to reflect that it only applies to a single user being loaded and if otherwise, differed to your answer.

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for your help my aim is to allow one user to see his own experience and not all the experience to all user of the apps. So If I understand your both answer, Jay give me the way to do my main request and Callam give me the way to perform an admin account ?

Comment: @flyer74 my answer also gives you a way to do your main request.